# Multi-Vendor extension for Magento

Tags: extensions, marketplace

Does anyone have any experience of a working multi vendor extension. I've looked at a few and they simply don't work well.

Could someone recommend please as been looking for months without success.

I would have thought there would be a de-facto available.

Appreciate a answer from someone who has had some success in this area.

I would consider Magento 1 and Magento 2.

Comment: "Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A
(see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) -
you'll get better results at the Magento forums (https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension)
or Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)

Answer (score 0):

In my company, we work once with the extension of Unirgy, uMarketPlace.

It is quite good, it has some things that we did not like but could be extended.

The main problem is that some parts of the module use iOnCube within the module.

Here's the link: https://www.unirgy.com//products/umarketplace/magento-multi-vendor-marketplace

It's ready to Magento 1 and Magento 2